# How to get JFrame as function argument in java?

Tags: java, jframe

I wanted to make a different function to make menubar for java application.

In menubar function `frame.pack()` in action listeners and `frame.setJMenuBar` statements are required.

So how can we pass frame as object to subclass as argument?
I get errors in

```
imports..

public class sjava {
  public static void CreateAndRunGUI() {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyFrame");

    code..

    MakeMenuBar(frame);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void MakeMenuBar(Object frame) {
    JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
    menubar.setBackground(new Color(180,160,130));
    menubar.setOpaque(true);
    menubar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,20));
    frame.setJMenuBar(menubar);
    JMenu menu1 = new JMenu("menu1");

    code..

    mitem1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        code..
        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
        frame.pack();
      }
    });
    code..
    mitem2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        code..
        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
        frame.pack();
      }
    });
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
  javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      CreateAndRunGUI();
    }
  });
}
```

Can `makemenubar` function be used without using frame as an argument?

Comment: cannot find symbol  symbol: method setJMenuBar(javax.swing.JMenuBar)  location: variable frame

Comment: Replace `Object frame` with `JFrame frame` in the argument list of `MakeMenuBar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to replace

```
public static void MakeMenuBar(Object frame) {...}
```

with

```
public static void MakeMenuBar(JFrame frame) {...}
```

otherwise no methods of class `JFrame` will be accessible.